# distinguish between segue that incomming to same view controller

Tags: ios, tags, tableview, segue, pass-data

I have three  view controller.A is table view,B in another table view with different data and C is detail for this tableviews. A and B is going to C with different segues  and pass their data to C and  C retrieve their data in viewdidload method.

All thing i want is that how i will find out which segue was performed  therefore set proper data for it ?

Comment: just create a Bool in VC C like `var isComeFromA: Bool` and set that in the `prepareForSegue` in parent VC

Comment: thank you.its solve my problem.